# What permissions do I need to grant a user that wants to view the definition of a stored procedure, function, view or trigger?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

If I want to allow a user to see the definition of a database object that they are not allowed to select or execute how would I do that?

Comment: must be the owner of the object or superuser. alternative execute over a function with that show the info compiled with a super user and SECURITY DEFINER to be executed by the low access user.

Comment: What makes you think they can't now? This information comes from the system catalogs and anyone can look at them. Try `select * from pg_proc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few exceptions like `pg_authid`, all PostgreSQL metadata tables are readable by `PUBLIC`, that is everybody. In particular, you can get the function definition with

```
SELECT prosrc
FROM pg_proc
WHERE proname = 'myfunc';
```

(The source of new-style SQL functions would be stored in parsed form in `prosqlbody`.)

Comment: Can you please help me one this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72996231/get-maximum-number-of-job-slaves-per-instance-that-can-be-created-for-the-execut