# Get maximum number of job slaves per instance that can be created for the execution in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, cron, job-scheduling, pg-cron

I am migrating oracle database to postgresql.

While migration came to know with the following query in the oracle side.

Oracle Query:

```
SELECT
TRIM(value) AS val
FROM v$parameter
WHERE name = 'job_queue_processes';
```

I just want to know how can we get the maximum number of job slaves per instance that can be created for the execution at the postgresql side.

I have created `pg_cron` extension and created required jobs till now. But one of the function is using above query in oracle, so I just want to convert it into the postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) is usually a good source of information.

> Important: By default, pg_cron uses libpq to open a new connection to the local database.

In this case, there is no specific limit.  It would be limited in the same way other user connections are limited.  Mostly by `max_connections`, but possibly lowered from that for particular users or particular databases by the ALTER command.  You could create a user specifically for cron if you wanted to limit its connections separately, then grant that user privileges of other roles it will operate on behalf of.  I don't know what pg_cron does if the limit is reached, does it deal with it gracefully or not?

> Alternatively, pg_cron can be configured to use background workers. In that case, the number of concurrent jobs is limited by the max_worker_processes setting, so you may need to raise that.

Note that the max number of workers may have to be shared with parallel execution workers and maybe with other extensions.